# BeautifulSoup - Pagination error on the last page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The battle to finish my first **scraping** script continues. I think that I'm almost finishing but I hit a new roadblock.

So, the problem is that when I reach the last pagination page I'm getting this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/scripts python/scrape_learn/ttc_quase.py", line 50, in <module>
    url_tag = soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"}).find('a')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I think that the error is related with the way I'm finding url_tag, but I'm not seeign any other way to grab the "next page". I tried to use the Try/Except method but when apply it I just get the listings on the first page.

So I'm not sure what should be my next step. If someone could help I will appreciate.

My full code:

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://timetochoose.co.ao/?ct_keyword&ct_ct_status&ct_property_type&ct_beds&search-listings=true&ct_country=portugal&ct_state&ct_city&ct_price_to&ct_mls&lat&lng"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

anuncios_ttc = {}
anuncios_nr = 0

while True:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    print(response)

    data = response.text

    print(data)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

    anuncios = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "grid-listing-info"})

    for anuncios in anuncios:
        titles = anuncios.find("a",{"class": "listing-link"}).text
        location = anuncios.find("p",{"class": "location muted marB0"}).text
        link = anuncios.find("a",{"class": "listing-link"}).get("href")
        anuncios_response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
        anuncios_data = anuncios_response.text
        anuncios_soup = BeautifulSoup(anuncios_data, 'html.parser')
        conteudo = anuncios_soup.find("div", {"id":"listing-content"}).text
        preco = anuncios_soup.find("span",{"class": "listing-price"})
        preco_imo = preco.text if preco else "N/A"
        quartos = anuncios_soup.find("li", {"class": "row beds"})
        nr_quartos = quartos.text if quartos else "N/A"
        wcs = anuncios_soup.find("li", {"class": "row baths"})
        nr_wcs = wcs.text if wcs else "N/A"
        tipo = anuncios_soup.find("li", {"class": "row property-type"})
        tipo_imo = tipo.text if tipo else "N/A"
        bairro = anuncios_soup.find("li", {"class": "row community"})
        bairro1 = bairro.text if bairro else "N/A"
        ref = anuncios_soup.find("li", {"class": "row propid"}).text

        anuncios_nr+=1
        anuncios_ttc[anuncios_nr] = [titles, location, bairro1, preco_imo, tipo_imo, nr_quartos, nr_wcs, conteudo, ref, link]
        print("Título", titles, "\nLocalização", location, "\nPreço", preco_imo, "\nLink", link, "\nReferencia", ref, "\nTipo", tipo_imo, "\nQuartos", nr_quartos, "\nWC", nr_wcs, "\nBairro", bairro1, "\nConteudo", conteudo)

    url_tag = soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"}).find('a')
    if url_tag.get('href'):
        url = url_tag.get('href')
        print(url)
    else:
        break

print("Nr Total de Anuncios: ", anuncios_nr)

anuncios_ttc_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(anuncios_ttc, orient = 'index', columns =['Titulo', 'Localização', 'Bairro', 'Preço', 'Tipo', 'Quartos', 'WCs', 'Descrição', 'Referência', 'Ligação'])

anuncios_ttc_df.head()

anuncios_ttc_df.to_csv('ttc_python.csv')
```

Comment: Obviously `soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"})` returns None. The least you can do is avoid using two functions on the same line where the second function depends on the result of the first function. In this case, two time find(). This won't solve the problem, but makes it a lot easier to debug the code and locate the source of an error.

Comment: Hi Ronald, thanks for the time you took answering. So:

"soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"}).find('a')" It's a bad practice? 

In this case I need to get a step back and to try to find a better way to retrieve the next page links. Thank you

Comment: Split it as: `temp = soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"})` and on the next line `url_tag = temp.find('a')`. As I said, it doesn't solve the problem, but it is much easier to see that `temp` has become `None`.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that, and restart from that point.

Comment: You are trying to use the same variable for loop variable and iterable. _for anuncios in anuncios:_  change the first to anuncio and the code inside the loop should then work with anuncio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question ended up to be provided in other thread where I was trying to identify better the URL_Tag element.

With the help of @Andrej Kesely I was able to solve the problem with:

```html
    url_tag = soup.find('li', {"id": "next-page-link"})
    if not url_tag:
        break
    url = url_tag.find('a')['href']
```

Now the script is able to run until the end and to generate the csv file as intended.